# Linux VM Custom logs not collected in Azure log analytics

Tags: linux, azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to collect custom log file from a Linux VM in Azure Log analytics.
I have created a Log analytics workspace, created a custom log by uploading the file and providing a path to collect from linux machine /var/logs/myapp/*.log
Installed the linux agent in the VM
The VM is shown as connected in the Azure log analytics workspace and I could even see the heartbeat logs.
However no custom logs are being collected.
Thought it could be latency issue but the logs didnt get collected for almost a day.
I have checked the NSG of the VM and it allows both inbound and outbound to internet.
I have even granted access to the log file using sudo chmod 775 filename.log

Is there anything else that has to be checked or any way to troubleshoot this. It would be really helpful.Thank you!

Comment: As a first step, can try to run the - Log Analytics Troubleshooting Tool And check the scenario why Agent custom logs aren't working & follow resolution mentioned in the below document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agent-linux-troubleshoot#issue-you-are-not-seeing-any-custom-log-data